# When whoever vs. whomever fails the he/him test

Tags: subjects, predicate, whoever-vs-whomever

The following example fails the he/him test for whoever/whomever:

> Please give the key to whoever needs to open that cabinet.

Give the key to him or he? Give the key to him.

However, when asking who opened that cabinet, he works instead.

So the question, then, is which part of the sentence do we perform the trick on? The predicate is "open that cabinet," which would mean whoever does take on the subject and is correct here. But why isn't "give the key" the predicate?

Comment: The answer to that question was extremely complex and beyond my skill level to understand. Also, I think my question is different in that parts of the sentence fail the he/him test, which makes answering it correctly an illustrative case and useful for people on the site.

Comment: I don't think the situation is different. As the question there says, we use "he" in "He created it" but "him" in "Put me in touch with him". It is a complicated answer, but it's kind of a complicated topic. The basic answer is to use "whoever", as long as it sounds acceptable to you in this sentence

Comment: I'd just like to know why the trick works when asked of "who opened the cabinet" and not the first part. If anything, the order is reversed in the duplicate candidate. And again, it's an advanced answer. I'm confident there's a simpler way to explain it for the lay student.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your answer or the duplicate answer. What about "please give the key to whomever"?

Comment: I see, sorry that the linked post didn't help. I'm a little confused about where you're coming at this from. Why are you sure that there's a simpler answer (do you have a particular one in mind)? Why do lay students need to know "tricks" about when to use "whoever" vs. "whomever"?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VbXRddlCB8&list=PLi01XoE8jYojEo9eoxfyNRROy4ojL6eh0&index=6 skip to 4:13. I'm assuming the answer has to be "whoever." I'm just trying to figure this out.

Comment: I see, thanks for giving some context. In my opinion, "who" vs. "whom" (and "whoever" vs. "whomever") is not actually an appropriate topic to cover in material aimed at beginners.

Comment: The creator of the video probably was thinking of a rule like the one tchrist advocates.

Comment: What is the he/him test? Do you need to pass it to get a tourist visa to the US?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *he/him* test is much overrated, especially when it comes
without instructions for use in complex sentences.

Let's parse it as a statement, not an order, ok?

- *He'll give the key to **whoever** needs to open that cabinet*

is indeed correct. *Whomever* would be ungrammatical. That follows the actual rule.

The reason why the *he/him* test doesn't work here 
is that the *wh-ever* word is
not only
  - **after** the preposition *to* (where *him* would work),
but also
  -  **before** the tensed verb *needs* (where *he* would work).

So the question is whether the *wh-ever* word is (respectively)
  - the object of the preposition *to*
or
  - the subject of the verb *needs*.

Elimination gives the answer. It has to be one or the other.

- On the one hand, if it's the object of the preposition, it can't be the subject; but then what **is** the subject of *needs*? This is a tensed clause, and they require a subject. That's a problem.
- On the other hand, if it's the subject of *needs*, then that requirement is filled, but what's the object of *to*? Well, it's the whole *Wh*-complement clause (which is in fact a noun phrase and can be an object or a subject) *whoever needs to open that cabinet*. That clause describes and refers to the indefinite person who is the legitimate receiver of the key, the one who needs it. So that's no problem.

By elimination, then, it's *whoever*.

Comment: It even remains *whoever* if the decoy *to* is removed via dative alternation: *Please give **whoever** needs to open that cabinet the key.* For one reason or another, that one doesn’t seem to confuse people half so often as the *to* version does.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you and GO BLUE!

Answer (score 0):

What John Lawler is trying to say there above is this: *who needs to open the cabinet* is an embedded question.
English speakers do not inflect *the man* and so do not need to inflect *who ...*.

In other words: A lone *whom* does not work as determiner (whereas "this is what" does), nor, as you noted, in the determiner phrase.