# Should I use "who" or "whom" in "The main problem of Argentina comes from whom has taken office."?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-case, whom, grammatical-roles, prepositional-objects

Should I use *who* or *whom* in this sentence?

1. The main problem of Argentina comes from **whom** has taken office.

## My logic

I know that *whom* is an object pronoun, that *whom has taken the office* is the object, and that *The main problem of Argentina* is the subject.

I also know that *who* can be replaced with subject pronouns such as *he, she, they* and *whom* with object pronouns like *him, her, them*.

My confusion comes from the fact that I can replace it both ways:

2. Argentina has a problem. It comes from him.

Here *Him* replaces *whom has taken office*.

3. Argentina has a problem. He has taken office.

Here *He* replaces *who*.

## My second question

That leads to my second question: can you use *whom* and *who* interchangeably when it’s the object?

Comment: If you're unsure whether to use _whom_ or _who_, **Don't Use _Whom_**.

Comment: *Who* is the subject of the verb *has taken* just as *office* it that verb’s object — whereas **the entire clause** *Who has taken the office* is in turn the object of *from*. These are different things completely.  A clause can itself be a grammatical object; you never mark what's in the clause based on the clause's own grammatical role. You only inflect single words for case, not entire clauses. You cannot use *whom* as the subject of a verb, and since you need a pronoun inflected as a subject, it ***must*** be *who*. And this is a duplicate, which I shall locate momentarily.

Comment: See my answer here: [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579120/give-this-work-to-whoever-looks-idle-or-give-this-work-to-whomever-looks-idl/579122#579122)