# What to do when a relative pronoun seems to be both object and subject?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, pronominal-agreement

Consider the following:

1. I congratulate him.
2. He won the race.
3. I congratulate him who won the race.

I think these are straight-forward. The object of the main clause becomes the subject of the relative clause, so I have switched from accusative *him* to nominative *who*.

But what about where a single relative pronoun is used:

4. I congratulate who(m?)ever won the race.

Should the relative pronoun be considered accusative, as the direct object of "congratulate", or nominative, as the subject of "won", or can the entire relative clause be considered the direct object of "congratulate", leaving "whoever" as the correct choice?

Comment: The duplicate contains the sentence "I saw the man who I think was mad," which is the same construction.

Comment: "Whoever" is preferable, but Ssee my answer here [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579120/give-this-work-to-whoever-looks-idle-or-give-this-work-to-whomever-looks-idl/579122#579122)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I think this may be different case. Your example is a transposition of "This is the man whom I saw." with changes. My question regards the combining of "the man" and "who" such that it not so easily decomposed as two main clauses. Edit: I see there are a few other duplicates, my title was just poor.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you. I take it you would disagree the relative clause itself can be considered a direct object of the main verb?

Comment: Actually, "who(m) ever won the race" is not a clause but a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction understood as "the person satisfying the description 'x won the race'".

Comment: So it is! Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It looks similar, but it is different in an important way that bears specifically upon the OP's question. In "I saw [**the man** [who I think was mad]]" the object of the verb *saw* is headed by the noun **man** and the relative clause occurs as a modifier of this noun within the nominal/noun phrase. There is no way that *who* there can be construed as the object of *saw*. ...

Comment: @AndrewLeach In contrast, in the OP's example, "I congratulate [**who(m)ever** won the race]", the object of the verb *congratulate* is the NP (more specifically, the used relative clause construction) headed by the word *who(m)ever*. There is no preceding NP being modified by a relative clause. The contrast is brought out by considering the OP's previous example "I congratulate [**him** [who won the race]], where the word *him* clearly heads the object of *congratulate*. Notice this word disappears/is replaced by *who(m)ever* in the OP's main example. I think this question deserves reopening!

Comment: I thought my answer here [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579120/give-this-work-to-whoever-looks-idle-or-give-this-work-to-whomever-looks-idl/579122#579122) dealt with the case of the pronoun "who(m)ever".

Comment: @AndrewLeach [This is indubitably the best question to link it to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166847/put-me-in-touch-with-whomever-created-it). And it might also be very useful to readers to merge these questions with useful, but not nearly so accurate/full/nuanced/supported answers with that question: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508258/when-whoever-vs-whomever-fails-the-he-him-test) and [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579120/give-this-work-to-whoever-looks-idle-or-give-this-work-to-whomever-looks-idl?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know that would be a lot of work, but it would be really useful for readers and you'd get a superb page of high quality answers! A worthy labour of love :)

Comment: Classically, 'the rule' mandates 'I congratulate whoever won the race' (_a person_ won the race, subjective) BUT 'I congratulate whomever they chose as president' (they chose _a person_, objective), so the case determined by the function of the 'who/m/ever' in the retrievable sentence, not in 'I know X'. However, modern advice is usually to avoid 'whomever'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not what the science says ... :)

Comment: @Araucaria There's lies, .... Looking closely at the first 10 recent-ish Google examples (via ngrams) for 'whomever', I find 3 erroneous uses, 3 correct if sounding archaic, and 4 examples discussing proper usage in dated grammars.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, that confirms what the science says. There's no rule when the free relative is the object of the matrix clause and the *-ever* pronoun is the subject of the free relative (or vice versa). Your investigation found that the rule you cite works in 50% of cases (in other words it's not a real rule!)

Comment: @Araucaria 'The rule' used with scare quotes and obviously belonging to prescriptivist philosophy cannot be deduced from actual usage studies, only from looking at pre-21st century grammars that addressed the problem. You wish to add the _relevant_ scientific data?

Comment: A *whoever* or a *whomever* clause is not affected by its part in the sentence (e.g. as a direct object). Pick the right pronoun for the clause, then put the clause back in the sentence. ***I congratulate whoever won the race*** (*whoever* is the subject in the clause). ***I congratulate whomever you selected as winner*** (*whomever* is the object in the clause).

Comment: @TinfoilHat "who(m)ever you select as leader" is not a clause, though. It's a noun phrase.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. : In my world, *whomever you select as leader* is called a "nominal relative clause."

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, in traditional grammar, because they involve a structure that is in many ways similar to a relative clause, they were called 'causes' for a long time. The term "nominal relative clause" is a bit of a fudge. It appears to say that they are clauses that are 'nouny'. However, they appear in places that no other clauses and only nouns appear, for example in determiner function. Perhaps more tellingly, whereas clauses functioning as subjects always take singular verb agreement, free relatives/fused relative constructions take singular or plural verb agreement: ...

Comment: @TinfoilHat And this is according to whether they are grammatically singular or plural NPs. Consider: *Whichever pens she chooses always **work** well" and "Whichever pen she chooses always **works** well". With what we now know about the grammar there's no doubt they're NPs, not clauses :)